# Speed up drupal 6 solr indexing

Tags: search

We have 90,000 nodes and it and we run cron every 10 minutes and do 200 documents per cron run. At this rate it will take just over 3 days to index all the content. It is also indexing older content first.

1. Is there a way to index newer content first
2. Is there a way to index more than 200 per cron run?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the settings at `admin/settings/apachesolr`.

If your server has enough capacity, I'd run the cron more often and increase the limit.

Check also [this](http://drupal.org/node/908468) thread and [be sure to disable core search indexing](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/performance-tip-disable-drupals-core-search-indexer-when-using-apache-solr).

Not sure though about indexing newer nodes first.

Comment: Some sane suggestions there in the thread. The Elysia Cron option might suite well for a site of this size.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the questions can be answered in the affirmative. It's just that both of those things require custom code. So I sufgest you try the Elysia Cron or Drush routes first, as specified in the thread Ivanhoe123 linked to.

The point of indexing older content first, I believe, is that otherwise it might take a very long time for the indexer to reach the nodes that have been edited or inserted longest ago.